# How to edit /sys/ in Android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, root

Is there any way to edit /sys/ folder in Android. I've tried these:

1. Granted root permission to ES File Explorer and edited a file in /sys/. R/W permission is enabled in ES file explorer.
2. With a terminal emulator, tried this:

   `su`

   `chmod 777 /sys/filename`

After that I edited the file, but the two methods do not seem to be working.

Is there any method where I can go in the kernel and edit those files in /sys/?

Comment: do you have root access to the device?

Comment: @Neeraj the /sys directory is special in Linux.  The contents are typically dynamic.  Which file entries in /sys do you want to change and why?

Comment: @DroidChris Yes, I have the root access.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) (`adb`) is a versatile command-line tool which you can use to communicate with a device (an emulator or a connected Android device).

### adb over network

```
adb connect <IP Address>:5555
adb devices //To Confirm host computer is connected to the target device)
adb devices -l //Query for devices 
adb remount //Remount the partitions /system, /vendor in read-write mode
adb shell //To debug the kernel through adb
```

### adb over serial:

```
adb devices 
adb devices -l
adb remount
adb shell
```

> In case adb connection lost then you can try by resetting the adb host through `adb kill-server` and then run the above commands.

### EDIT:

Permission of `sysfs` is defined in kernel space so you can not directly create the files or directory in `/sys` folder from the user space. If you want to *create/modify* the *directory/file* then I think you can achieve it through kernel module. There are loads of helper function that can be used to create the file attributes and directory inside `/sys`.

I belive already your driver will be using those helper function (something like **`sysfs_create_group`** or **`kobject_create_and_add`**). For changing the file permission and data *read/write* check your driver **`__ATTR`** and **`show/store`** function.

It should be something like

```
static ssize_t fo_show(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute 
*attr,char *buf){
}
static ssize_t fo_store(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute 
*attr, const char *buf, size_t count){
}

static struct kobj_attribute baz_attribute =
__ATTR(foo, 0666, fo_show, fo_store);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @tangrs thanks for the pointing out. In Linux I know  *we create the directory and file inside `/sys` through kernel module*. In case of android I was pointing the `/system` not `/sys`. I will update my answer for the same.

Answer (score -1):

on ADB have you asked to remount the device? Do the following:

```
adb remount (./adb on apple)
adb shell (./adb apple)
cd sys
chmod 777 filename
```

you should be able to also create or delete directories too

Comment: `/sys/` is a special directory in Linux. I don't see how this will allow you to 'edit' (if that even makes sense for sysfs) the files in it.

Comment: On a rooted device you should be able to edit it. Could it possibly damage things, yes! But that wasn't the question now was it?

Comment: No, what I mean is it's meaningless to 'edit' files in sysfs as it's not a real filesystem. It's a psuedo-filesystem that lets you change/view certain kernel parameters by reading and writing to psuedo files. I don't see how you would meaningfully create or delete 'directories' either in `/sys/` from userspace (what would that even mean?). Have you tested editing, creating or deleting files in `/sys/`?

Comment: I have not edited files in the sys folder. The point I am trying to make here is that the question was how to edit the sys folder, not if it was the right thing to do.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this answer then. If it's meaningless to edit the virtual directories in sysfs, then what's the point of explaining how to do it? A question made on false assumptions shouldn't have a pointless answer.

Comment: It's not even about whether it's _right_ or _wrong_. Trying to treat sysfs as a real filesystem is literally meaningless and makes no sense. It's like someone asking how to toast bread in a washing machine. Sure, it's possible to tell them how to put a piece of bread in a washing machine but that doesn't make it useful.